# Chart not rendered properly

Tags: php, phpexcel

I have a small table

[image: My table]

and want to create a `TYPE_DONUTCHART` with the PHPExcel library. I took the example code from the [`Examples/33chartcreate-pie.php`](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/blob/develop/Examples/33chartcreate-pie.php) file and adapted it accordingly:

```
$dataseriesLabels2 = array(
    //new PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues('String', 'Summen!$A$1', NULL, 1),
);
$xAxisTickValues2 = array(
    new PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues('String', 'Summen!$B$1:$C$1', NULL, 2),
);
$dataSeriesValues2 = array(
    new PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues('Number', 'Summen!$B$2:$C$2', NULL, 2),
);
```

The file is served by the script, but when I try to open it, an error message occurs:

> We found a problem with some content in "Myfile.xlsx". Do you want us to try to recover as much as we can? If you trust the source of this workbook, click Yes.

When I click Yes and activate editing on the document, I get the following message like this:

> Excel has finished the check and repair of your file. Some parts of this file have been repaired or discarded.
>
> Removed part: Part /xl/drawings/drawing4.xml. (drawing form)

What's wrong in my code? What do I have to modify?

Notes:

- As you can see, I'm using another dataset than in the example. There's only data in the range `A1:C2` (see screenshot above).
- The worksheets name is `Summen`, I double checked, that the problem is not a typo of the sheet.
- It's been asked in the comments, I have already tried removing the comment from the `dataseriesLabels2` entry.

Comment: Probably commenting out the `$dataseriesLabels2` entry is the cause of the problem

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. But it's not, I removed the comment but still have the same problem.

Comment: Plus: It shouldn't (by design), the `PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues::_construct` has an empty `array()` as default value.

Comment: The file you're basing it on contains two charts, are you getting a clash between the two? I've just created a file that builds a single chart from your data

Comment: No, it only contained one chart when the error occured (I added a bar chart in the meantime and want to have two charts at the end, but at that time there was only one chart). Did no error occur with your example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My example

```
$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
$objWorksheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();
$objWorksheet->fromArray(
    array(
        array('Whatever', 'Cat1', 'Cat2'),
        array(77,         247,    128),
    )
);
$objWorksheet->setTitle('Summen');

$dataSeriesLabels1 = array(
//    new PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues('String', 'Summen!$A$1', NULL, 1),
);

$xAxisTickValues1 = array(
    new PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues('String', 'Summen!$B$1:$C$1', NULL, 2),
);

$dataSeriesValues1 = array(
    new PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues('Number', 'Summen!$B$2:$C$2', NULL, 2),
);

$series1 = new PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeries(
    PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeries::TYPE_DONUTCHART, // plotType
    NULL,                           // plotGrouping
    range(0, count($dataSeriesValues1)-1),      // plotOrder
    $dataSeriesLabels1,             // plotLabel
    $xAxisTickValues1,              // plotCategory
    $dataSeriesValues1              // plotValues
);

$layout1 = new PHPExcel_Chart_Layout();
$layout1->setShowVal(TRUE);
$layout1->setShowPercent(TRUE);

$plotArea1 = new PHPExcel_Chart_PlotArea($layout1, array($series1));
$legend1 = new PHPExcel_Chart_Legend(PHPExcel_Chart_Legend::POSITION_RIGHT, NULL, false);
$title1 = new PHPExcel_Chart_Title('Test Pie Chart');


$chart1 = new PHPExcel_Chart(
    'chart1',       // name
    $title1,        // title
    $legend1,       // legend
    $plotArea1,     // plotArea
    true,       // plotVisibleOnly
    0,          // displayBlanksAs
    NULL,       // xAxisLabel
    NULL        // yAxisLabel       - Pie charts don't have a Y-Axis
);

//  Set the position where the chart should appear in the worksheet
$chart1->setTopLeftPosition('A7');
$chart1->setBottomRightPosition('H20');

//  Add the chart to the worksheet
$objWorksheet->addChart($chart1);


$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
$objWriter->setIncludeCharts(TRUE);
$objWriter->save(str_replace('.php', '.xlsx', __FILE__));
```

generates correctly without any errors

Comment: I see, the problem was the `PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeries::GROUPING_STANDARD` option. I have to use `NULL` instead. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Pies/donuts have no concept of grouping data at all

Comment: Yeah, makes sense. Then the examples should be corrected (which also don't work properly)!

Comment: Which specific examples? `33chartcreate-pie.php` is certainly correct

Comment: Oh yeah, right. I was referring to the example of the [latest stable release](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/blob/master/Examples/33chartcreate-bar.php). My bad. To sum it up: Thanks a lot! :-)